# MEF 2 - No exports were found that matched the constraint for constructor with multiple overloads

Tags: c#, .net, mef

Error:

```
The composition produced a single composition error, with 2 root causes. The root causes are provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
    ContractName    MyNonMefInterface
    RequiredTypeIdentity    MyNonMefInterface

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'MyMefClass..ctor (Parameter="myNonMefClass", ContractName="MyNonMefInterface")' on part 'MyMefClass'.
```

Is there anyway to tell MEF to **NOT** try to import "myInterface"? Its an optional param that gets defaulted already if it isn't passed in to the constructor:

```
public MyMefClass() : (new MyNonMefClass()) {}
public MyMefClass(myNonMefInterface myNonMefClass) {
    _myNonMefClass = myNonMefClass;
}
```

I'm using MEF 2's new attribute less configuration and doing my RegistrationBuilder like so:

```
var builder = new RegistrationBuilder();
builder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IMyMefClass>().ExportInterfaces();
...
var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();

aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MyMefClass).Assembly, builder));

var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog, CompositionOptions.DisableSilentrejection);
```

Basically I'm always setting the default of MyNonMefClass in the default constructor but allowing myself to overload it for testing. Its not setup for MEF and coming from another dll so if I could just tell MEF to ignore it and use the constructor without params instead that would be the easiest solution. Anyone know how to do that?

Edit: I was able to resolve it by setting the  `[ImportingConstructor]` tag on the empty constructor, but that means I have to reference MEF in that project as well, would I be able to do it through the new fluent API using the RegistrationBuilder somehow instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer, there is a `SelectConstructor` method:

```
builder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IMyMefClass>().SelectConstructor(ctors =>
{
    var minParams = ctors.Min(ctor => ctor.GetParameters().Length);
    return ctors.First(ctor => ctor.GetParameters().Length == minParams);
}).ExportInterfaces();
```

That will pick the least amount of params, where it defaults to picking the most. Hope that helps someone else! :)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/01/getting-started-with-convention-based-part-registration-in-mef-version-2.aspx

Comment: Where did you got .SelectConstructor and the ctors.Min and ctor.GetParameter? I don't have it...

Comment: @GutembergRibeiro are you using MEF 2 or MEF 1? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/01/getting-started-with-convention-based-part-registration-in-mef-version-2.aspx has some more details and I'll add it to my post as well

Comment: The weird think is that I have no contructor at all, so it implies that the default parameterless ctor would be called, but Idk why it still gives the following error:

The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) Method not found: 'Void PI.Switch.Hosting.AppBase..ctor(System.String)'.

Comment: ALso, I'm using the latest version of .Net/MEF

Comment: @GutembergRibeiro I'd recommend making a new question for it so you can put some code / details up, feel free to link it to me so I can help you figure it out :)

Answer (score 2):

To get optional imports in MEF, you should use [**Optional Imports**](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Declaring%20Imports). For example in your code:

```
public MyMefClass([Import(AllowDefault=true)]myNonMefInterface myNonMefClass) {
    _myNonMefClass = myNonMefClass;
}
```

Comment: I was already able to fix it by using the `[ImportingConstructor]` attribute, but I was hoping to be able to do it from the new fluent API with the `RegistrationBuilder` so I don't have to have my exported classes even know anything about MEF (they currently don't have an `[Export]` attribute as that is handled by `RegistrationBuilder`